# For a numpy array having shape (2,2) why imshow command shows a range of values along x and y-axis? what these values are?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]I want to show filter weights as color using imshow. But I'm getting a range of values along y-axis and also along x-axis. I expect that there must be only 2 xtick labels and 2 ytick labels. How can I overcome this problem?

```
a = np.array([[0.1665, 0.2390],[0.2034,0.0694]])
plt.imshow(a,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you show an image, Matplotlib automatically figures out the x-axis and y-axis labels.  If you want to override this, you need to manually set the ticks yourself.  Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) and [`matplotlib.pyplot.yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html) to do so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.1665, 0.2390], [0.2034,0.0694]])
plt.imshow(a, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=0, vmax=1)

# New
plt.xticks(list(range(a.shape[1])))
plt.yticks(list(range(a.shape[0])))
```

For setting the x and y labels, I've created a list going from 0 up to as many elements in each dimension so that each filter weight is represented as one location in the representative image.  One final note is that if you don't specify the minimum and maximum intensities to be visualized in the image, it will default to the smallest and largest values in your 2D array.  Assuming your weights span between `[0,1]`, set the `vmin` and `vmax` attributes in the `imshow` call to 0 and 1 respectively.

We get:

[image: Weights]

Comment: If I use aspect='auto' I get correct range 500 but x-axis is still a range of values. What this range of values along x-axis represent? In actual code I have to plot (500,2) array in the form of imshow.

Comment: Each axis represents the corresponding pixel coordinate of the image, so the x-axis would vary from 0 to 1 while the y-axis varies from 0 to 499.  You're using `imshow`, so naturally the axes represents the pixel coordinates in the image.

Comment: I have added a figure which shows a range of value.Top left box is from -0.50 to 0.50 why is is to. In this box pixel value should be 0.1665.

Comment: @jerry The weights are visualized as **intensity values**.  They will **not be visualized on the axes**.  You are unfortunately misunderstanding the purpose of the labels in `imshow`.  If you want the filter weights to go on the axes, you need to use something else - perhaps a scatter plot?

Comment: If pixel have higher value its intensity will be higher and for low value it should be dark. But I want to know about the range of values along x-axis and y-axis. What they are and how we can give explanation about this?

Comment: Look at the centre of each pixel.  That is an image coordinate.  Each pixel has a 1 x 1 area, so each pixel spans 0.5 pixels above and below, same for the left and right.  There's really no other way for me to explain this and I'm going to stop our discussion here.

Comment: Ok but for top left box value is 0.1665 where as the central value is 0.00.

Comment: And if Simply specify xticks  after using aspect='auto' will it be a right way?

Comment: Oh yes - you can set the min and max values.  If you don't do this, by default it will use the smallest and largest values to map to 0 and 1.  I'll change my answer.  Also setting the aspect to `'auto'` shouldn't change anything regarding  how to interpret the axis labels.